# Why does Jupyter Notebook "forget" Cython from one cell to the next?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cython

When I compile a cell with cython, it seems Jupyter forgets the compiled function in the next cell. This seems to me to be not right. What is going wrong?

I am using version 5.0.0 of the notebook, and

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

Here is a MWE that produces the problem:

Cell 1:

```
%load_ext Cython
```

Cell 2:

```
%%cython
cdef int foo():
    return 3

print(foo())
```

This produces:

```
3
```

In the next cell, I have

```
print(foo())
```

This produces:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9701608cebc0> in <module>()
----> 1 print(foo())

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess it's because you didn't defined your `foo` function as available in python (with `cpdef`) but only only give it a C signature (with `cdef`) so it can only be called from cython code.
In the cell 2 you can call it because you are still using cython code but in your cell 3 you are back in pure python and the function isn't available. There is various way to get the result from the `foo` function in python :

```
%%cython
# Not reachable in pure python:
cdef int foo():
    return 3

# Python visible function signature:
cpdef int foo2():
    return 3

# Or a wrapper around the cython function:
def foo3():
    return foo()
```

You can now try to call `foo2()` or `foo3()` in your python code.

See one of the relevant part of the [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html) if you haven't see it.

Comment: Great, thanks! Thanks for the doc pointer, too. I find it generally hard to find documentation that helps me to use cython in Jupyter. I guess some of the tings that confuse me is that a lot of the cython-specific things are hidden in the magic commands.